# Using regex to remove everything that is not in between '<#'something'#>' and replace it with commas

Tags: c#, regex, string, c#-4.0

I have a string, for example

```
<#String1#> + <#String2#> , <#String3#> --<#String4#>
```

And I want to use regex/string manipulation to get the following result:

```
<#String1#>,<#String2#>,<#String3#>,<#String4#>
```

I don't really have any experience doing this, any tips?

Comment: Where are the commas in your expected result?

Comment: Oops completely forgot about it, I'll quickly add it

Comment: Can an escaped `<` or `>` occur within the bracketed strings?

Comment: They won't no, it would only be alphanumeric values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do something like this, and it depends on exactly what you need.  However, if you want to use a single regex operation to do it, and you only want to fix stuff that comes between the bracketed strings, then you could do this:

```
string input = "<#String1#> + <#String2#> , <#String3#> --<#String4#>";
string pattern = "(?<=>)[^<>]+(?=<)";
string replacement = ",";
string result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replacement);
```

The pattern uses `[^<>]+` to match any non-pointy-bracket characters, but it combines it with a look-behind statement (`(?<=>)`) and a look-ahead statement `(?=<)` to make sure that it only matches text that occurs between a closing and another opening set of brackets.

If you need to remove text that comes before the first `<` or after the last `>`, or if you find the look-around statements confusing, you may want to consider simply matching the text that comes between the brackets and then loop through all the matches and build a new string yourself, rather than using the `RegEx.Replace` method.  For instance:

```
string input = "sdfg<#String1#> + <#String2#> , <#String3#> --<#String4#>ag";
string pattern = @"<[^<>]+>";
List<String> values = new List<string>();
foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern))
    values.Add(m.Value);
string result = String.Join(",", values);
```

Or, the same thing using LINQ:

```
string input = "sdfg<#String1#> + <#String2#> , <#String3#> --<#String4#>ag";
string pattern = @"<[^<>]+>";
string result = String.Join(",", Regex.Matches(input, pattern).Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just after string manipulation and don't necessarily need a regex, you could simply use the string.Replace method.

```
 yourString = yourString.Replace("#> + <#", "#>,<#");
```